# copying only selected properties to a new object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of keys which I am interested in like

```
fillable = ['name', 'lastname', 'address' ]
```

and the `request` object can send any number of params

I want to create a new data object which consists of only variables represented by `fillable` array

Is there a better way to do this, without looping ? in ES6 or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `reduce`

```js
let request = {name: 'John', lastname : 'Doe', address: 'bla bla', age : 67, gender : 'M' }
let fillable = ['name', 'lastname', 'address']

let newObj = fillable.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v]: request[v] || ""}), {});

console.log(newObj);
```